# Calling a method from within another method of the same class

Tags: java, methods, method-call

I have a number of methods which need to implement my *add* method, however I am not sure how to go about doing this, as all the methods are in the same class - ArrayPhoneDirectory.

Add method:

```
private void add(String name, String telno) {
    if (size >= capacity)
    {
        reallocate();
    }
    theDirectory[size] = new DirectoryEntry(name, telno);
    size = size +1;
}
```

The following are methods which require add to be called:

load:

```
public void loadData(String sourceName) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sourceName).useDelimiter("\\Z");

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        String telno = scan.nextLine();

        DirectoryEntry newdir = new DirectoryEntry(name, telno);

        //ADD THE NEW ENTRY TO THE DIRECTORY
    }
}
```

addChangeEntry:

```
public String addChangeEntry(String name, String telno) {
    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        if (x.getName().equals(name)) {
            x.setNumber(telno);
            return x.getNumber();
        } else {
           // add a new entry to theDirectory using method add   
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It is probably something very obvious, however I am still fairly new to java so any help as to how to call these methods would be much appreciated!

Comment: @tod I think he was asking how to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `add(name, telno)` and it will work.

In fact your `add` method is private, so it can only be called from *inside* the class.

For example, in your load method:

```
public void loadData(String sourceName) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sourceName).useDelimiter("\\Z");

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        String telno = scan.nextLine();

        // You don't need this, add builds its own DirectoryEntry from name and telno
        // DirectoryEntry newdir = new DirectoryEntry(name, telno);

        add(name, telno);
    }
}
```

And you can do exactly the same in `addChangeEntry`